# Function to return the first rows in which one column values sum is greater than a number R

Tags: r

I would like to select the first rows from a data frame on the condition that the sum of values from a column is greater than a certain number. For example take the data set cars. Say I want to select rows based on values in the second column. If my number is 7 then the first and second rows will be selected the values in the second column for the first two rows being (2+10)> 7); if the number is 34, the first 4 rows will be selected (2+10+4+22 >34)

I tried the following which returns all the rows irrespective of the input value

```
foo<-function (z) {
  for (i in 1: nrow (cars)) {
  if(sum(cars[i,2])<z) {
    sum(cars[1:i,2])
  } else {
    return (cars[1:i,])
     }
  }
  return (cars[1:i,])
}
```

I also tried using `while`, but ended up with only the first value being returned endlessly.

Comment: i think `cumsum` would be much better. please share a sample data and also the expected output based on that sample

Comment: Use `cumsum`, add another column as the cumsum, then select based on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `cumsum` with `which`

```
cars[seq(which.max(cumsum(cars$dist)>34)),]
```

and this can be made into a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, col, thresh){
         dat[seq(which.max(cumsum(dat[[col]])> thresh)),]
 }

f1(cars, "dist", 34)
#   speed dist
#1     4    2
#2     4   10
#3     7    4
#4     7   22

f1(cars, "dist", 7)
#   speed dist
#1     4    2
#2     4   10
```

Comment: Guess `seq_len(findInterval(thresh,cumsum(cars$dist))+1)` might be more efficient.

Comment: @nicola Thanks, I was just testing with `findInterval`, but didn't use the `cumsum` part, thanks for it.  As this is a different option, would it be better you post as an answer.